# Entity Framework ThenInclude filtered from original dataset

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a query where my ThenInclude Where needs to access data in the original data set e.g.

```
var bikes = context.Bikes
.Include(bike => bikes.Models)
.ThenInclude(model => model.Spec.Where(spec=> spec.SpecYear == bike.YearCreated ))   
.ToList();
```

I currently have this in two separate queries but it would save a lot of time if I completed this request on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use projection instead of `Include`:

```cs
var bikes = context.Bikes
    .Select(bike = new Bike
    {
        Id = bike.Id,
        // ... other fields

        Models = bike.Models.Select(m => new Model
        {
            Id = m.Id
            // ... other fields

            Spec = m.Spec
                .Where(spec => spec.SpecYear == bike.YearCreated)
                .ToList()
        })
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, I never thought to use linq like this.